# XML Animation Effects Android

Tags: android, android-animation

I am totally new to XML Animation and i was studying about animating views where i came across the terms

```
  android:fromXScale="0.0"
  android:fromYScale="0.0"
  android:toXScale="1.0"
  android:toYScale="1.0"
```

Why are these terms used? How to decide what float value to use?

Comment: Have you seen the docs yet? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#scale

Comment: @AL. Yes , but still does not get it.

Answer (score 1):

These terms are use for animation effects. Like you are scaling one object from specific X,Y coordinates to another.

1) `fromXScale` & `fromYScale` - use for starting position for scaling the object(Starting X / Y size offset)

2) `toXScale` & `toYScale` - use for ending position for scaling the object(Ending X / Y size offset)

Reference link - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html

Hope it will help!

Comment: I am asking how to decide that starting and ending position

Comment: See the float values are in between 0.0 and 1.0 so it's like true/false. In case of alpha value, if you want to set visibility to true then you can use 1.0 or if you want false then use 0.0, If you want partially visible view then you can use 0.5

Comment: I am asking about fromXscale and toXscale

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html), where it clearly explains how to set the float values.

An extract from the article:

```
android:fromAlpha
```

Float. Starting opacity offset, where 0.0 is **transparent** and 1.0 is **opaque**.

Comment: I have read the documentation but no where is given how to set the values. just this for x starting , starting X size offset, where 1.0 is no change

Comment: From the docs: A resizing animation. You can specify the center point of the image from which it grows outward (or inward) by specifying pivotX and pivotY. For example, if these values are 0, 0 (top-left corner), all growth will be down and to the right. Represents a ScaleAnimation.
attributes:
 `android:fromXScale`
Float. Starting X size offset, where 1.0 is no change.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Read Detail from given link and understand its usage [**Full Link.**](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/)

Comment: is that like 1 and 1 are normal sizes and we give relative values like i want to do it 3 times bigger i will give 3 value?

Comment: You can use different the rule is just keep `fromXScale` and `fromYScale` values less then `toXScale` and `toYScale`. give it a try.